# How do you design a micro-app Blazor project?

Tags: asp.net-core, microfrontends

I have been tasked with creating a unified UI for my current company for our Blazor Apps. We have 15 or so apps and we need to add more.

Our current requirements are:

1. UI appears the same
2. The Menu must be dynamically generated from a DB

With these requirements I can't just create a component library with a Layout Component because that would require each app to pass the menu data to the layout component.

We really want to create something similar to Google's App Suite (One login, multiple apps, same UI). While researching how to have one UI, and hopefully only one authentication call, I came across this article (https://gorillalogic.com/blog/four-micro-frontend-architecture-types-you-can-implement-with-blazor).

The Method 1 section from the above article (Use micro-apps with a shared session and parameters) seems like the way to go. The article states, "To do this with Blazor, every app is a Blazor project and they have shared session information between them (see illustration below)."

[image: Micro-Frontend]

I am not entirely sure how you would even design something like this in Blazor. How can you create a shared session between Blazor Apps when each runs on it's own Kestrel server? Is there some type of way to creating an outer "container" app that houses the other apps?